# How can I order mysql results alphabetically using a union

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two separate queries that I'm unioning together to return a large list of items (this is for an autocomplete function). Here is my mysql:

```
SELECT Title
FROM search 
Where Title is not null
Union
SELECT Name
From authors
```

and my list that gets returned looks like this for example:

```
Angels and Demons
The Davici Code
The Lost Symbol
Dan Brown
JK Rowling
```

However, I want to be able to order ALL the results in acending order together. Like this:

```
Angels and Demons
Dan Brown
JK Rowling
The Davici Code
The Lost Symbol
```

How can I apply an Order By clause to sort everything? This seems kind of simple yet I'm having trouble finding the solution online.

Comment: Add your `ORDER BY` at the very bottom. It would apply to all records.

Comment: I tried that, but I would have to select what to Order By. I want to Order By BOTH Title and Name. Not one then the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R Doolabh.

Add ORDER BY Title ASC below. The UNION will creates a new result wich columns names will be the same as the first SELECT.

If it doesn't work, you can try this too:

```
SELECT Title
FROM search 
WHERE Title IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Name AS Title
FROM authors
ORDER BY Title ASC
```

Regards.